# Fallbacks for XSLT 2.0 processor in 3.0 stylesheet

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, backwards-compatibility

For parsing some strings, I want to use `analyze-string()`, if available, and provide a slower fallback that works with XSLT 2.0.  This is a quick test I did:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize" 
      use-when="not(function-available('analyze-string'))">
    2.0
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize" version="3.0"
      use-when="function-available('analyze-string')">
    3.0
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="function-available('analyze-string')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I ran this inside oXygen 15.2 with Saxon-PE/EE 9.5.1.3.  Strangely, the output is

```
2.0
true
```

which indicates that the first template was included rather than the second, although its `use-when` attribute should have evaluated to true, as the second line of the output indicates.  What went wrong?

Are there standard best practices when developing a stylesheet targeted at both 2.0 and 3.0 processors?  Saxon HE accepts the stylesheet if I use the option `-xsltversion:2.0` to override the version attribute on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.  I also tried to set the version attribute to 2.0 to make overriding superfluous, but then `function-available('analyze-string')` will evaluate to false in Saxon PE/EE, even if I prefix it with the XPath functions namespace.

Comment: I have tried your code with Saxon 9.7 HE/PE/EE and all three output `3.0 true`.

Comment: I think HE 9.7 officially supports XPath 3.0/3.1 expressions and functions in XSLT version 3.0 stylesheets, but not any XSLT 3.0 elements. Michael Kay  wrote in his announcement of 9.7: "9.7 also includes a complete implementation of XPath 3.1 and XQuery 3.1....Many of the new features including maps and arrays are in the open-source HE product, though for higher-order functions you need to move to the Professional Edition."

Comment: Thanks, I just tested that (new XPath functions work in HE, but not XSLT 3.0 elements).  So I guess the unexpected result I get with PE/EE 9.5.1.3 might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Saxon 9.5, for reasons which now escape me, the static context for use-when expressions includes only the core XPath 2.0 functions plus a few selected XSLT functions such as element-available, system-property, and function-available; it doesn't include XPath 3.0 functions such as analyze-string, even though these are available in "ordinary" XPath expressions within the stylesheet. I suspect this reflects the state of the XSLT 3.0 specification at the time Saxon 9.5 was released in 2013. The situation will have changed in 9.6 and 9.7.